# ScheduledExecutorService one thread many tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I am new to `ExecutorService` and wonder why following code prints correctly "10 15", even though I have created only one thread to process the timeouts? Why can I call schedule many times without previous tasks being cancelled on a single thread executor?

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class TestExecutorService implements Runnable {
    public static ScheduledExecutorService SERVICE = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    private int delay;


    public TestExecutorService(int delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    public void run () {
        System.out.println(delay);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SERVICE.schedule(new TestExecutorService(10), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        SERVICE.schedule(new TestExecutorService(15), 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        SERVICE.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: an additional read http://code.nomad-labs.com/2011/12/09/mother-fk-the-scheduledexecutorservice/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reading the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()) would be very helpful in this case. It does explain that though the executor will be created with a single thread, it will be operating with an *unbounded* queue. This means that you can submit multiple tasks to the executor and they will be queued up to run one after the other, up to the maximum bounds of the queue (which in this case is infinity) or until the JVM runs out of resources.

> Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an
>   unbounded queue. (Note however that if this single thread terminates
>   due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will
>   take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.) Tasks are
>   guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be
>   active at any given time. Unlike the otherwise equivalent
>   newFixedThreadPool(1) the returned executor is guaranteed not to be
>   reconfigurable to use additional threads.

In your example your two tasks get queued up, and run sequentially one after the other, which is why you get the (expected) output.

Comment: so if many tasks with same delay are submitted then some of them would print much later?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Yes, they would, assuming that the tasks take long enough for you to notice.

Answer (score 14):

From the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor%28%29):

> Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be active at any given time.

The difference between "processing timeouts" and "task execution" is the key to the answer. You assume that "single-threaded" means "processing only one timeout at a time", but it really means "executing only one task at a time". All the timeouts are processed simultaneously, but if one timeout is reached before a task stops executing, it will have to wait for the other one to finish before it can execute.